# Docker exec -it <image> bash leads to an empty folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After running docker-compose, I run `docker exec <image> bash`, in folder(e.g) laravel. This folder is empty, on my pc, but on 3 another machines, this folder contain sync folder.

Any idea to solve this, or maybe someone had same problem?

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'
services:
    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: ./php-fpm
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-70
        volumes_from:
            - application
        expose:
            - "9000"
        links:
            - workspace
    application:
        build: ./application
        volumes:
            - ./application/:/var/www/laravel
    data:
        build: ./data
        volumes:
            - /var/lib/mariadb:/var/lib/mariadb
            - /var/lib/redis:/data
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        volumes_from:
            - application
        volumes:
            - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        links:
            - php-fpm
    mariadb:
        build: ./mariadb
        volumes_from:
            - data
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: taplend
            MYSQL_USER: taplend
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123
    redis:
        build: ./redis
        volumes_from:
            - data
        ports:
            - "6379:6379"
    beanstalkd:
        build: ./beanstalkd
        ports:
            - "11300:11300"
        privileged: true
        links:
            - php-fpm
    beanstalkd-console:
        build: ./beanstalkd-console
        ports:
            - "2080:2080"
        links:
            - beanstalkd
    workspace:
        build:
            context: ./workspace
            args:
                INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO: ${INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO}
        volumes_from:
            - application
        tty: true
```

Every service has own directory in root directory. Every directory has its own **Dockerfile**

> PS: I changed OS to *Windows 10 Pro* and folders became sync via dockerTools (docker beta didn't synchronized folders). I think, topic must be closed

Comment: You do not `docker exec <image>`, it only applies to running containers. Provide details on the definition of your container so we may better assist.

Comment: its not burning problem, because we bypassed it. docker-compose.yaml:

Comment: I updated post because it is bad practice to ignore people that try to help

Answer (score 0):

Check the "shared drives" settings - on Windows and Mac only directories in certain paths can be shared by default.

For the new Docker for Windows see here: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#/shared-drives

Also do a `docker inspect {container}` ([see docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/)) and look for the mount/volume info.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I used ubuntu, another team members used windows. I changed OS from ubuntu 16.04 to windows 10 pro. Trying use docker via docker(beta) gave the same result. Only using DockerTools helped me and folders became sync.